# Comparing 2 datetime lists and finding the closest match

Tags: python, timedelta, python-datetime

I have a list of dates that I need to compare with another list of dates based on how close they are...

```
List1 = ['2017/03/27 23:01:45', '2017/03/28 02:00:10', ...]
List2 = ['2017/03/27 22:35:18', '2017/04/24 05:30:24', ...]
```

(Datetime objects in both lists)

I am comparing the time difference as follows:

```
from datetime import timedelta

for dates1 in range(0, len(list1)):
      for dates2 in range(0, len(list2)):
           date_difference = list1[dates1] - list2[dates2]

           if timedelta(hours=0) <= date <= timedelta(hours = 12):
                   do something....
```

The issue I am having is I am sometimes getting 2 or more dates that fit this criteria of dates being within 12 hours of each other... I want the CLOSEST one to the date difference and just use that... but I'm not sure how to do so with this kind of design....

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean closest to the difference? Largest or smallest difference?

Comment: Also, you have strings or `datetime` objects in your list?

Comment: Smallest difference :)

Comment: They are datetime objects...

Comment: 1) Sort both lists

2) For each member of first array

2.1) Search for the last one that is smaller than that member and for the first  one that is bigger (unless there is one that is equal to that member)
The search of (2.1) should start from the last match we found

Answer (score 2):

```
closest_dates = [min([d2 for d2 in list2 if d2 >= d1], key=lambda d: d - d1)
                 for d1 in list1]
```

Comment: This is not accurate. It only checks the difference. Does not check the `timedelta` is positive or bounded beneath 12 hours.

Comment: This seems like a good solution... but it only works by finding the closest pair entirely... I need each element in list1 to match with an element closest to it in list2... So there are multiple matches.... tried implementing it with your solution but to no avail :(

Comment: @arsenal88 updated. So now you have a list of dates coming from list2 which line up with the date from list1, so `zip(list1, closest_dates)` will give you pairs.

Comment: Compiling closest_dates gives me a syntax error:  Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

Comment: @arsenal88 oops, fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```
for d1 in List1:
    for d2 in List2:
        print(abs(d1 - d2)
        if abs(d1 - d2) < r:
            new_d1 = d1
            new_d2 = d2
            diff = abs(d1 - d2)

In [39]: new_d1
Out[37]: '2017/03/28 02:00:10'

In [39]: new_d2
Out[39]: '2017/03/27 22:35:18'

In [38]: diff
Out[38]: datetime.timedelta(0, 12292)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generator function to return dates that **match** your criteria and then the take pair with the minimum time difference:

```
from itertools import product

def interval_diff(x, y):
    for dt1, dt2 in product(x, y):
        diff = dt1 - dt2
        if timedelta(hours=0) <= diff <= timedelta(hours=12):
            yield dt1, dt2, diff

date1, date2 = min(interval_diff(list1, list2), key=lambda x: x[2])[:2]
```